# Decorations behave strange with tcolorbox frames

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, decorations

I'm trying to change how the frame of a tccolorbox looks like. The decoration works fine with a normal tikzpicture, but looks really odd when used as the decoration for a tcolorbox.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} % to try using zigzag decoration
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{decorate diamonds/.style={decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step #1*sqrt(2) with {
            \draw [rotate=45] (-#1/2, -#1/2)  rectangle (#1/2, #1/2);
        }
    }}}
    \tikzset{decorate diamonds/.default=2pt}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        decorate diamonds=2pt,
        radius=1cm,
    ]
        \draw (0,0) [decorate] --(2, 0)
            arc[start angle=90, end angle=0]
            -- +(0, -2)
            arc[start angle=0, end angle=-90]
            -- +(-2, 0)
            arc[start angle=270, end angle=180]
            -- +(0, 2)
            arc[start angle=180, end angle=90]

            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        frame style={decorate diamonds=2pt, decorate},
        colback=white
    ]
        hi there!

        hello!

        why hi there!
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: 2pt diamonds]

In the tikzpicture, the decoration looks as intended. But in the tcolorbox, the decoration looks... strange. It is like the diamonds "fold in" on themselves. One thing that *might* provide insight is using the zigzag decoration, which I originally used to try to make this diamond pattern, or making the markings larger. Below is the output for the same code, but the width of each diamond is `6pt`:

[image: 6pt diamonds]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem that we can test your solutions.

Comment: @zarko The snippet is a full document now.

Comment: This does not compile for me. I get 
'! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.44     \end{tcolorbox}'
Does it work for you?

Comment: @Plergux It compiles for me. I am using lualatex for it. One of the answers points out this is necessary, but I am unsure why.

Comment: @Beelzebielsk Ah, I see. That kind of thing is probably also worth a mention when you ask a question. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inner `\draw` used in `mark=between positions 0 and 1 step #1*sqrt(2) with={...}` is influenced by the (outer) value of tikz option `rounded corners=<dimension>`. Note this option is indirectly set to `1mm` by `tcolorbox` option `/tcb/arc`. Resetting to `sharp corners` works.

BTW, the problem is reproducible when the decorated path uses non-zero `rounded corners=<dimension>`. And I have to use luatex to avoid "dimension too large" error.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} % to try using zigzag decoration
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{decorate diamonds/.style={decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step #1*sqrt(2) with {
            % note the added option "sharp corners"
            \draw[sharp corners, rotate=45] (-#1/2, -#1/2)  rectangle (#1/2, #1/2);
        }
    }}}
    \tikzset{decorate diamonds/.default=2pt}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        decorate diamonds=2pt,
        radius=1cm,
    ]
        \draw (0,0) [decorate] --(2, 0)
            arc[start angle=90, end angle=0]
            -- +(0, -2)
            arc[start angle=0, end angle=-90]
            -- +(-2, 0)
            arc[start angle=270, end angle=180]
            -- +(0, 2)
            arc[start angle=180, end angle=90]

            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        frame style={decorate diamonds=2pt, decorate},
        colback=white
    ]
        hi there!

        hello!

        why hi there!
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]